# Angular failed to instantiate modules in production build

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, gulp, bower, angular-module

I'm trying to add features requiring new third party modules to an Angular app, using gulp and bower. Everything is fine in dev mode but any new modules I add produce the notorious `"Failed to instantiate module"` error in production. I have tried disabling the uglify build step and it made no difference. Simply declaring the new module as a dependency to one of my own is enough to produce the error.

Unlike in many of these questions I am already using the string array syntax for dependencies and the app is already functioning with various other modules. I see no difference between what I'm adding and the other libraries already in use.

Here is my current attempt at including `ngCookies`, but I've done the same thing with others eg. `ngFileUpload` with the same results.

**bower.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "angular": "^1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.5",
    "extras.angular.plus": "^0.9.2",
    "moment": "^2.10.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.15",
    ...
    "angular-cookies": "^1.5.9", // new
  },
```

**index.html:**

```
<!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/extras.angular.plus/ngplus-overlay.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
...
<script src="/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script> // new
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**core module declaration:**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core', [
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngSanitize',
      'blocks.exception',
      'blocks.logger',
      'blocks.router',
      'ui.router',
      'firebase',
      'ngMap',
      'ngplus',
      'ngCookies', // new
    ]);

})();
```

**minified/uglified js output:**

app.js

```
function(){"use strict";angular.module("app.core",["ngAnimate","ngSanitize","blocks.exception","blocks.logger","blocks.router","ui.router","firebase","ngMap","ngplus","ngCookies"])}(), ...
```

lib.js

```
t.module("ngCookies",["ng"]).provider("$cookies", ...
```

**console output:**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.core due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCookies due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngCookies' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/nomod?p0=ngCookies
```

Comment: Always make sure, All angular plugins should have same angular version, likewise I can say you should have all of your angular plugin version should be `1.5.8` as I can see you have angular-sanitize version `1.4.8` which isn't correct.. I'm not sure my suggestion would help you or not, Its suggestion from my side

Comment: @PankajParkar Thank you, I'm not sure how I managed to overlook that or why it didn't show up in dev mode, but it seems to be working now.

Comment: If you want then I can add it as in answer, may be it could help other person as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you had different version of angular API loaded and bounded together. Ideally you should refer the angular API library with same version. But in your case you had `angular-animate` which has `1.4.8` version but other angular API has `1.5.8` version. Which may internally conflict.

Rather I'd suggest you to have all angular API version same as 1.5.8. This could solve your problem.